# Why does the button not change color with this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web dev and am just doing some exercises related to HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I have created a button in my html file and want to change the color of the button if it is clicked on.

This is my HTML code:

```
<button id="box" style="padding: 20px; background-color: black;"></button>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.id === 'box') {
        document.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
})
```

Not quite sure why it is not working.

Comment: You're trying to change `document.style`, which doesn't exist. You need `event.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: _“Not quite sure why it is not working”_ — Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 2):

`document` doesn't have a `style` property (at least, not by default in spec-compliant browsers). Your developer console should inform you of this with a message akin to:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor')`

Instead, be a bit more specific as to which element's background color you'd like to change. In the example below, I've modified your code to target [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body), which has a `style` element:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.id === 'box') {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
})
```

```html
<button id="box" style="padding: 20px; background-color: black;"></button>
```